# PHP-FPM and SSLKEYLOGFILE issue

Tags: php, ubuntu, wireshark

I have configuration with Ubuntu, Apache and php-fpm (the version of php is 7.4). My goal is to be able to store the TLS keys in order to decrypt TLS traffic in Wireshark. I usually achieve this using the environment variable SSLKEYLOGFILE but it doesn't seem to work with php-fpm. The environment variable is added in the fpm pool's config file. For testing purposes use the following PHP script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
```

I want to note that it successfully writes keys to the file when execute the script using the cli but doesn't write anything when use php fpm. Here is the config of the php fpm pool:

```
[example]

user = user
group = user
clear_env = no
env[SSLKEYLOGFILE] = /my/path

listen = /run/php/php7.4-fpm_example.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Any ideas how can i fix it ?

Comment: Does the user under which PHP runs have write permission on the directory?

Comment: Is the channel between webserver and FPM encrypted at all? it's usually an internal-only network, encryption would add a huge overhead..

Comment: @Olivier Which directory did you mean ? The user has all necessary permissions for writing in the log file.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I haven't added any encryption explicitly so think that there is no encryption between the webserver and FPM. However it is not in significant matter for the problem because i tried to execute the script directly (not through Apache) with cgi-fcgi and the result was same. So i believe that it is FPM related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to extract the pre-master keys using a debugger. [Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80158/extract-pre-master-keys-from-an-openssl-application) i found a [link](https://git.lekensteyn.nl/peter/wireshark-notes/tree/src/sslkeylog.py) to a script written by Peter Wu that automate the process using GDB and Python. The only problem was that the default version of libssl on Ubuntu has no debugging symbols. However exists an Ubuntu repository in which there are debug versions of all binaries from the official repository. I enabled it using the instructions from section "Getting -dbgsym.ddeb packages" in [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) Ubuntu Wiki page. Then installed libssl with debugging symbols:

```
 apt install libssl1.1-dbgsym
```

Finally i ran the python script with the following command:

```
PYTHONPATH=.   gdb -q -ex  'py import sslkeylog as skl; skl.start("premaster.txt")' -p 65774
```

where 65774 is the process id of the corresponding php-fpm process.